# Передать переменную из одного метода в другой

Tags: c#

как сделать что бы в консоль выводился result?

```
namespace metodi
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] massiv;
            Console.Write(result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        void rewenie()
        {
            int[] massiv = new int[] { 10, 23, 14, 5, 20, 10, 14, 5, 3, 23 };
            var result = massiv.Distinct().ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Объявить что rewenie возвращает не `void`, а `int[]`:

```
static int[] rewenie()
```

Вернуть результат:

```
int[] massiv = new int[] { 10, 23, 14, 5, 20, 10, 14, 5, 3, 23 };
var result = massiv.Distinct().ToArray();
return result;
```

Ну и использовать для вывода:

```
Console.Write(rewenie());
```

Как-то так в итоге:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write(rewenie());
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static int[] rewenie()
{
    int[] massiv = new int[] { 10, 23, 14, 5, 20, 10, 14, 5, 3, 23 };
    var result = massiv.Distinct().ToArray();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Лишнее объявление в `Main`

Comment: @aepot О, не заметил! Спасибо, убрал.